# Python Flask is only displaying one frame from live video in browser that's streaming from OpenCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, flask

I've run into a strange problem as this was working last night and just broke to my knowledge I have not made any changes. So I have opencv streaming from my raspberry pi over a socket connection to my remote machine. I then plan to pass this into flask to display this on a webpage where a user can look at the live feed.

client.py

```
import cv2
import io
import socket
import struct
import time
import pickle
import zlib

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(('ec2 instance id', 8089))
connection = client_socket.makefile('wb')

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cam.set(3, 320);
cam.set(4, 240);

img_counter = 0

encode_param = [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 90]

while True:
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    result, frame = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame, encode_param)
#    data = zlib.compress(pickle.dumps(frame, 0))
    data = pickle.dumps(frame, 0)
    size = len(data)


    print("{}: {}".format(img_counter, size))
    client_socket.sendall(struct.pack(">L", size) + data)
    img_counter += 1

cam.release()
```

now this is where my code gets a bit messy I'm not the best when it comes to python. I know this socket code below could be separated into a different class and stuff.

server.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
from flask import make_response
import cv2
import socket
import sys
import cv2
import pickle
import numpy as np
import struct ## new
import zlib
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    """Video streaming home page."""
    return render_template('index.html')


def gen():
    """Video streaming generator function."""
    HOST=''
    PORT=8089

    s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print('Socket created')

    s.bind((HOST,PORT))
    print('Socket bind complete')
    s.listen(10)
    print('Socket now listening')

    conn,addr=s.accept()
    data = b""
    payload_size = struct.calcsize(">L")
    print("payload_size: {}".format(payload_size))
    while True:
        while len(data) < payload_size:
            print("Recv: {}".format(len(data)))
            data += conn.recv(4096)

        print("Done Recv: {}".format(len(data)))
        packed_msg_size = data[:payload_size]
        data = data[payload_size:]
        msg_size = struct.unpack(">L", packed_msg_size)[0]
        print("msg_size: {}".format(msg_size))
        while len(data) < msg_size:
            data += conn.recv(4096)

        frame_data = data[:msg_size]
        data = data[msg_size:]

        frame=pickle.loads(frame_data, fix_imports=True, encoding="bytes")
        frame = cv2.imdecode(frame, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        #vc = cv2.VideoCapture(frame)
        #below I am looping through frame and converting them back to byptes
         so I can display them in the browser as an image 

        for data1 in frame:
            data1 = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)[1].tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' +data1+ b'\r\n\r\n')



@app.route('/video_viewer')
def video_feed():

    return Response(gen(),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, threaded=True)
```

Now when I run these, one image is just displayed to me instead of a constant feed of images. like I said this method did work last night. My guess would be that there is something wrong with my loop? `for data1 in the frame:`. Apologies for the badly written socket code. Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

output from flask as you see once the first image frame is received it creates a new get request which stops the live feed

[image: output from flask as you see once the first image frame is received it creates a new get request which stops the live feed]